# Как на C# скомпилировать и подключить другой файл не имея Visual Studio и дополнительных компиляторов?

Tags: c#

Как на C# скомпилировать и подключить другой файл не имея Visual Studio и дополнительных компиляторов?
Суть в том. Указываю программе документ .pdf, .doc -она генерирует exe-шник и в него вшивает файл. А потом пользователь запускает exe, вводит,например,пароль и этот .pdf, .doc файл копируется в папку с приложением.
Читал, что .Net имеет компилятор, потому,что дополнительно на других компах никто не будет устанавливать ещё ПО.

Comment: Тут точно нужен exe-шник? ZIP, закрытый паролем, не годится?

Comment: да,именно exe нужен

Answer (score 3):

Можно скомпилировать программу без использования IDE, в данном случае Visual Studio.

Microsoft поставляет консольный компилятор csc.exe.

О том, какие аргументы передавать командной строке можно почитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Важно, что бы на машине стоял нужный Framework и либы.

Comment: А ещё дополнительный вопрос- а как "вложить" тот же самый doc файл, как ресурс?

Comment: @RakzinRoman https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c0tyye07.aspx